# AspNetCore Odata 8.0 Get single entity 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, microsoft.aspnetcore.odata

I recently started using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData (version 8.0.0) package, and I have an issue when implementing on retrieving a single entity in the controller, which returns a 404 Not found respond when I try to request the URL. The following is my code and configuration, thank you for looking into it:

**Packages**

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData(8.0.0)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(6.0.2)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer(6.0.2)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools(6.0.2)
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection(6.0.0)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging(6.0.0)

> Targeting framework: .NET 6.0

> Project: ASP.NET Core Web API

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContext")));

// Add services to the container with odata
var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
odataBuilder.EntitySet<User>("users");
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options =>options.AddRouteComponents("v1",odataBuilder.GetEdmModel()).Filter().Select().OrderBy().SetMaxTop(100).SkipToken().Count());
```

**User.cs**

```
[Table("User")]
    public class User
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        [MaxLength(256)]
        [Column("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(256)]
        [Column("Surname_en")]
        public string Surname_en { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(256)]
        [Column("Firstname_en")]
        public string Firstname_en { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Column("Surname_cn")]
        public string Surname_cn { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Column("Firstname_cn")]
        public string Firstname_cn { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(1024)]
        [Column("Email")]
        public string? Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("CreatedDate")]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

**UsersController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter;

public class UsersController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;

        public UsersController(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 50)]
        public IQueryable<User> Get()
        {
            return _context.User.AsQueryable();
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<User> Get([FromODataUri] string id)
        {
            return SingleResult.Create(_context.User
                .Where(m => m.Id == id));
        }
}
```

The first Get function is **working** with the URL:

> https://localhost/v1/users

But the second function is **not working** with the URL, it returns a 404 Not found status code with no error message, and it did not hit the function at all (when I set a breakpoint on the line of the code):

> https://localhost/v1/users(test@123.com)

or

> https://localhost/v1/users('test@123.com')

or

> https://localhost/v1/users/test@123.com

Comment: No need to add [EnableQuery] on top of the second method. Have you tried without that attribute?

Comment: Not working either, thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having many tries, including changing NuGet packing version, adding and removing attributes, using other types of the variable for the primary key...etc. I have found out the solution is nothing to do with configuration, data types, and attributes. It is the **name of the parameter**!

The name of the parameter has to be written as `Key`

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<User> Get([FromODataUri]Guid key)
{
return SingleResult.Create(_context.User
                .Where(m => m.Id == key));
}
```

Now that it works well, with the parameter name is **Key**, regardless of me changed the type to Guid.

Comment: That is solve my problem too. Thank you very much. Why the name of the parameter has to be "key"? Do you know anything about it?

Comment: No idea, I am guessing the library is recognising it via the name rather than the attribute tag. I could be wrong